# Узнать на какой именно строчке кода завершилась программа

Tags: c++, qt, отладка

Как можно создать отладочный модуль , явно записывающий в лог , на какой именно строчке завершилось приложение ? C++ или Qt

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Но для начала воспользуйтесь отладчиком, вдруг там что своими глазами увидеть получится (а в 90% случаев это так).

Answer (score 3):

Логи для этого не лучшее решение. В среднем или крупном проекте слишком много писать придется, и производительность просядет заметно, запись в файл не дешевая операция.

Для этого лучше подойдут т.н. крешдампы (crashdump). Крешдапм это по сути по-байтовая запись всей памяти и стека в момент падения. Сам файл дампа создается либо самой программой если она смогла обработать падение, либо специальной монитор-службой (лучший вариант) которая должна быть настроена и запущена в системе. После получения крашдампа его можно загрузить в отладчике и не только посмотреть в каком месте произошло падение но и увидеть стек со значениями всех переменных. В общем все так же как и при обычной отладке.

Подробнее как работать с дампами на [Виндоуз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx) (анг.)

Comment: Большое спасибо .

Answer (score 0):

Если очень хочется, то можно сделать лог быстрый, но только внутри памяти с ограниченным размером. Сначала определите функцию обработки исключений: **std::set_terminate** , **std::set_unexpected**. Дальше создаёте глобальные переменные типа **std::string** для определения точки программы. В начале создаём массив **указателей** на строки. Внутри проги делаете контрольные точки:
 `*(startlog + indexlog) = & str ;
 indexlog = indexlog + 1 ;
 if(indexlog == endlog)indexlog = startlog ;`
Если прога с параллельным кодом, то ещё и повозится нужно с мютексами, либо с атомными операциями. В методе обработки просто вывести строчки  *indexlog..endlog , startlog .. indexlog-1*